# How to open a link in smartwatch from phone

Tags: wear-os

I would like to know how to open a link from a simple app that I have made to push a link from within the app from phone to open on the watch for example a link to google play store app to get downloaded on the smartwatch.

Thank you.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

See the docs here https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/wear/remote/interactions/RemoteActivityHelper

and an example here https://github.com/android/wear-os-samples/blob/d18c489ff415aa0fbb25c260e3aacdf50f7716e3/WearVerifyRemoteApp/Application/src/main/java/com/example/android/wearable/wear/wearverifyremoteapp/MainMobileActivity.kt

```
        Log.d(TAG, "Number of nodes without app: " + nodesWithoutApp.size)
        val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
            .addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_BROWSABLE)
            .setData(Uri.parse(PLAY_STORE_APP_URI))

        // In parallel, start remote activity requests for all wear devices that don't have the app installed yet.
        nodesWithoutApp.forEach { node ->
            lifecycleScope.launch {
                try {
                    remoteActivityHelper
                        .startRemoteActivity(
                            targetIntent = intent,
                            targetNodeId = node.id
                        )
                        .await()
```